# TCheckBox to filter dataset by a field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcheckbox

I'm trying to filter a dataset by one field when ticking a checkbox, the following is code what I have put together and thought was correct but it doesn't appear to be working, it brings back 0 records.

```
procedure TfrmCustomers.cbClick(Sender: TObject);
if cbActive.Checked = True then
with dmod.cds do
begin
  DisableControls;
  try
    Filtered := False;
    FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive,foNoPartialCompare];
    Filter := ('active LIKE true');
    Filtered := True;
  finally
    EnableControls;
  end;
end;
end;
```

The name of the field in the dataset is called 'active' and it stores a string of either 'true' or 'false'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field 'active' holds a string you should write:

```
Filter := ('active = ''true''');
```

Right now you are filtering on the boolean value True.
Also, why don't you use a boolean / bit field for this Active field?

Answer (score 0):

Change filter line like this

```
Filter := ('active = ''true''');
```

Comment: No. `LIKE` is slower, and is meant for use when you're using a wild card. If you're doing a match to specific content, use `=` instead.